# Пунктуация, обособленное определение

Tags: пунктуация, определения

> 1. Передо мной, в синей долгополой шинели, стоял старик, среднего роста, с белыми волосами, любезной улыбкой и прекрасными голубыми глазами.
> 2. На крылечке сидели низенький старичок, заросший до глаз бородой, и молодая женщина в дождевом плаще.

Не понимаю, почему обособляется 《в синей долгополой шинели》. Могу предположить, что это обособленное определение, отделенное от определяемого слова сказуемым 《стоял》.
Но почему тогда не обособляется 《в дождевом плаще》во втором предложении？Это дополнение？ Но случаи ведь схожие. Старичок в чем？- в шинели, в шинели какаой？- в синей, долгополой. Женщина в чем？- в плаще, в плаще каком？-в дождевом.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: Нельзя понять, почему качественно скопированное задание не привело к копированию правильного обращения с пробелами. Если пишете, то предполагаете, что это будут читать? Читать по Вашим правилам?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обособление несогласованных определений имеет **определенные особенности** по сравнению с согласованными определениями.

В частности **нормальная позиция** для несогласованного определения ― это расположение сразу после определяемого слова. Препозиция и расположение на расстоянии относятся к инверсии, поэтому несогласованное определение в этих случаях обособляется.

1) *Передо мной, **в синей долгополой шинели, стоял старик,** среднего роста, с белыми волосами, любезной улыбкой и прекрасными голубыми глазами.*

***В синей долгополой шинели*** ― инверсированная позиция определения; ***среднего роста*** ― нормальная позиция, но в этом случае обособляется весь однородный ряд. Кстати, обособление "среднего роста" ― авторское решение, его можно и не обособлять, но весь последующий ряд обособляется в обязательном порядке.

2) *На крылечке сидели низенький старичок, заросший до глаз бородой, и молодая женщина в дождевом плаще.*

***В дождевом плаще*** ― необособленное определение в нормальной позиции. Следует отметить, что если определяемым является слово с неопределенным значением (старик, женщина), то первое несогласованное определение чаще не обособляется, обозначая определяющий признак лица (остальные несогласованные определения будут считаться дополнительными, и поэтому их обособляют).

Comment: Все по полочкам! Если будет конкурс на лучший ответ, данный ответ может претендовать на первое место! Без шуток, мне очень понравилось.

Comment: Спасибо. Знаете, мне когда-то эта тема казалась довольно трудной, поэтому пришлось над ней поразмышлять, почитать правила в разных книгах, сравнить их и составить для себя небольшой конспект. Правда, я им больше не пользуюсь, как-то всё в голове уже  так уложилось.

Answer (score 2):

**Передо мной, в синей долгополой шинели, стоял старик, среднего роста, с белыми волосами, любезной улыбкой и прекрасными голубыми глазами.**

Несогласованное определение "в синей долгополой шинели" обособляется, потому что оно отделено от определяемого слова "старик".

> [§92. Обособленные согласованные и несогласованные определения:](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm)
>
> Примечание. Несогласованные определения могут стоять и перед определяемым существительным, например: В белом галстуке, в щегольском пальто нараспашку, с вереницей звездочек и крестиков на золотой цепочке в петле фрака, генерал возвращался с обеда, один (Тургенев).
>
> Обычно подобные несогласованные определения обособляются (на обособление несогласованных определений во всех нижеперечисленных случаях влияет их местоположение):
> .....
> в) если отделены от определяемого слова какими-либо другими членами предложения, например: После десерта все двинулись к буфету, где, в черном платье, с черной сеточкой на голове, сидела Каролина и с улыбкой наблюдала, как смотрели на нее (Гончаров) (независимо от того, выражено ли определяемое слово собственным или нарицательным именем); На румяном лице его, с прямым большим носом, строго сияли голубоватые глаза (Горький);

**На крылечке сидели низенький старичок, заросший до глаз бородой, и молодая женщина в дождевом плаще.**

[В том же параграфе](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm):

> В нейтральном стиле речи наблюдается устойчивая тенденция к отсутствию обособления таких определений, например: подростки в вязаных шапочках и пуховиках, постоянные обитатели подземных переходов.